# <br/> tag in a string not properly making a new line in html

Tags: javascript, json

My frontend retrieves JSON data from the filesystem and convert form the below data

```
"Lorem Ipsum \r\n Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum "
```

to

```
"Lorem Ipsum <br /> Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum "
```

using javascript's string replace method.

I want to show this string in html with proper line break in a following way.

```
"Lorem Ipsum
Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum "
```

Here is the code for the view:

```
<label>{{ formatJSON(string) }}</label>
```

`formatJSON` is Angular function which basically changes `\r\n` into `<br/>`.

how do I properly do this?

Comment: angular expressions only output text. Have to use `ng-bind-html` and include ngSanitize in app. Lots of other similar posts here about `ng-bind-html` and read the docs as it pertains to `$sce`

Comment: @charlietfl Can you give me an example?

Comment: Examples in docs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [ngBindHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml).

```
<label ng-bind-html="formatJSON(string)"></label>
```

Comment: do I need to add "$sanitize" in my controller?  If I do this way, all my string are not shown on the view.

Comment: Yes, you have. It says that on the link I provided.